# TypeError: e.footer.split is not a function

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to get the content of an embed footer, but I'm not sure how to do it. I was able to do it fine with a description, but the same code does not work for a footer. Here is what worked with the description:

````
const args = e.description.split(' ');
const map = args[3].split('verse');
message.channel.send("```yaml\n"+ map[0] +"choose " + dest + "\n```");
````

And this would get the 4th word and cut off before "verse". So the map could be universe, multiverse, finalverse, etc. I want to implement this same function to the footer, and get the words before "verse" in footer, but I get an error. I tried the same thing but just with footer instead of description:

````
const args = e.footer.split(' ');
const map = args[3].split('verse');
message.channel.send("```yaml\n"+ map[0] +"choose " + dest + "\n```");
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Here it is for anyone who stumbles on this:

````
const args = e.footer.text.split(' ');
const map = args[3].split('verse');
message.channel.send("```yaml\n"+ map[0] +"choose " + dest + "\n```");
````

I had to put `.text` after `.footer` for it to work